# Column order in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, android-sqlite, create-table

Using SQLite databases on Android.  Why would this table creation statement work

```
CREATE TABLE Person 
(
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    event INTEGER,
    biography TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(event) REFERENCES Event(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

while this one does not?

```
CREATE TABLE Person 
(
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    event INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(event) REFERENCES Event(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    biography TEXT
);
```

According to [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182962/best-practice-for-foreign-key-column-position-in-table), some folks place foreign keys prior to regular attributes, but I'm not able to achieve that.

You can try at [Sqlite Browser](https://sqliteonline.com) or [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> FOREIGN KEY(event) REFERENCES Event(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
> ```

This is a table constraint, and the [SQL syntax as understood by sqlite](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) requires them to come after column definitions:

[image]

The question you linked talks about FK columns, not table constraints. `event` is a FK column in your table.